# Why are all links opening in new tab with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using bootstrap on a page with a navbar. I'm currently experiencing two problems that I believe are related.

1) All navbar links are opening a new tab.
2) Collapsible elements, rather than collapsing or expanding when clicked are also opening a new tab. For instance, using example code, clicking on a collapsing element that involves this piece of code:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
```

Actually opens a new tab at http://domain/#collapse1

I believe these two problems are related.

From my `<head>`

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="http://.../include/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://.../include/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

But even when I load the css and js from bootstraps site, I get the same results.

An example of the navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="http://.../">home</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="http://.../portfolio/">Portfolio</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="http://.../cv/">CV<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="http://.../contact/">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
```

And yet, all of these open in new tabs. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have target="_blank" anywhere?

Comment: No. This would be the obvious thing, and even when I copy pure example code from the bootstrap website for instance I have the same effect.

Comment: It might be a script issue but it it is hard to tell. Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: Don't understand this use of the word fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Whether a link opens in a new window or not is almost always an individual user's browser setting. Does this issue occur consistently across different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I fixed it by adding the following:

Original Link:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="http:...">Home</a>
```

New Link:

```
<a class="nav-link" target="_self" href="http:...">Home</a>
```